# EJB-JPA Persistence Unit

Tags: jakarta-ee

In a single application(large-scale application) is it good practice to use multiple persistence units?

Which type of situations should I use multiple persistence unit?

Answer (score 0):

No. I would use multiple persistence units only if the app has to access multiple databases. If everything comes from the same database, I don't see any advantage in using multiple persistence units.

Comment: Dear Friends, can you please help me to provide me any example or any hints about Menu Item. I mean I want to show the menu items which will be Database driven. It will be very helpful for me.